# Detect scrolling event on listview with winjs

Tags: winjs, windows-phone-8.1

I need to load more items as soon as the user scroll to the end of my list view.

I tried to use the microsoft sample : http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListView-loading-behaviors-718a4673/view/SourceCode (scenario 2) but it seams that list view have not the same behavior in **windows phone 8.1**.

When I run the sample I can see that only viewable contents are loaded (eg 5items of 50). 
But for windows phone it does load all items.

I use this code :

```
listView.winControl.itemTemplate = this.incrementalTemplate;
incrementalTemplate: function (itemPromise, recycledElement) {
    if (!recycledElement) {
        recycledElement = document.createElement('div');
    }
    var renderComplete = itemPromise.then(function (item) {

        console.log(item.index);


        itemTemplate.winControl.render(item.data, recycledElement);
        return item.ready;
    }).done(function (item) {
        console.log("clp"+item.index);

    });
    return { element: recycledElement, renderComplete: renderComplete };
},
```

Items are loaded asynchronusly. I can see in my console that it print 50 times the index and 50times the clp+index. Even if my list just show 5 items at a time.

Also it seems that my listview never fired the loading state event

```
listView.addEventListener("loadingstatechanged", function (args) {
    //never fired
}, false);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The listview is in a hub, the solution was to add an onscroll event on the win pivot item:

```
 document.querySelector(".win-pivot-item-content").onscroll = function () {
                if (self.scrollAtBottom(this) === true) {
                    //load more
                }
            };

   scrollAtBottom : function(element){
        return element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop === element.clientHeight
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to subscribe to event when the `ListView` was scrolled, you can take `ListView's Scrollviewer` and subscribe to `ViewChanged` event. The only problem is that I do not know how it would look like in `winjs`, in `C#` it can look like that:

```
// method to pull out a ScrollViewer
public static ScrollViewer GetScrollViewer(DependencyObject depObj)
{
    if (depObj is ScrollViewer) return depObj as ScrollViewer;

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

        var result = GetScrollViewer(child);
        if (result != null) return result;
    }
    return null;
}

// subscription:
GetScrollViewer(yourListView).ViewChanged += yourEvent_ViewChanged;
```

Maybe it will help.

Comment: Strange, it's null in my case. Is this still correct in Windows Phone 8.1 when HeaderTemplate, FooterTemplate and ItemsTemplate are all set?

Comment: @MichaelK.Sondej What is `null` in your case? When do you call this method?

Comment: Yeah, I've put this after InitializeComponents in the page's constructor, that was a mistake. After moving the code to LoadState (I'm using the NavigationHelper) it works as inteded. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The comment voted here as solution does not work just like that out the box, however I found a solution to this problem starting from that. 
See my first answer on the issue I opened at https://github.com/winjs/winjs/issues/690#issuecomment-61637832 (includes code snippet)